# Exercise about exact sequence and pushout

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

The following is a commutative diagram in an abelian category. Assume that the rows are exact and that $h,k$ are epic.
$\require{AMScd}$
$$\begin{CD}
0@>>>a@>{f}>> b @>{g}>> c@>>> 0\\
@VVV @VVjV @VVhV @VVkV @VVV\\
0@>>>a'@>{f'}>> b' @>{g'}>> c'@>>> 0
\end{CD}$$

*How do I prove that $j$ is epic if the square $g,h,k,g'$ is cocartesian?* I proved the converse already, but  I'm stuck in this direction. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT.** I post this solution for completeness, since it seems different from the one given in the answer. I didn't use that $h,k$ are epic, and this hypothesis isn't useful in proving the converse of sentence in italics either, so I don't know why it was in text of the exercise.

Let $z:a'\to d$ be an arrow such that $zj=0$, and construct the pushout: $$\begin{CD}
a'@>{f'}>> b'\\
 @VVzV @VVp_1V \\
d@>{p_2}>> p 
\end{CD}$$ since $p_1hf=0$ and $g=\operatorname{coker}f$, there is $u:c\to p$ s.t. $ug=p_1h$. Being $g,h,k,g'$ a pushout, there is $v:c'\to p$ s.t. $vg'=p_1$, so that $p_2z=p_1f'=vg'f'=0$. Since $p_2$ is monic (it is the pushout of $f'$, that is monic), $z=0$.

Comment: the conclusion holds for arbitrary h and k; also the converse is true.

Comment: @EzioGreggio Do you want a proof with elements or without ? I mean, is it okay to prove it in the category of modules over a ring, (and then use Freyd-Mitchell Embedding theorem)

Comment: @Roland a proof without elements; I already tried to generalize a proof with elements, but I couldn't. (FME theorem is not a tool I can use in my course although we mentioned it)

Comment: @FabioLucchini I should have found a solution for the original exercise, but I can't generalize it as you suggest. I also found this result mentioned in a (very) few papers online, but always assuming that all the sides of the pushout square are epis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following commutative diagram:
\begin{CD}
a@>>>0\\
@VfVV @VVV\\
b @>{g}>> c\\
@VVhV @VVkV\\
b' @>{g'}>> c'
\end{CD}
By exactness of top row, $g$ is the cokernel of $f$, hence the top square is a pushout.
By pushout pasting lemma, the bottom square is a pushout if and only if the outer rectangle is a pushout as well.
The outer rectangle is a pushout if and only if $g'$ is the cokernel of $fh$.
By exactness of the top row, $f'$ is the kernel of $g'$.
Consequently, $g'$ is the cokernel of $fh$ if and only if $f'$ is the image of $fh$.
Finally, $j$ is epic if and only if $f'$ is the image of $jf'$, hence that of $fh$.

Comment: Thanks! I would've never figured it out